# Euler Trail and Regular Graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can Regular graph have Euler trail? I really don't know where to start. Should I look at the middle part of the Regular graph, both ends of the trail, or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

A graph has an Euler trail then it has 0 or 2 vertices of odd degree. Hence, not all regular graph admits an Euler trail. Take for example $K_4$.